# While looping same table on 2 fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, multiple-columns

I am trying to add incremental counting to 2 separate fields.
I have `FieldA` and `FieldB` in the same table and need to increment as in the example-

```
FieldA | ID1 | FieldB | ID2
ABC    | 1   | GREEN  | 2
ABC    | 1   | RED    | 3
ABC    | 1   | Yellow | 4
XYZ    | 5   | RED    | 6
DEF    | 7   | GREEN  | 8 
DEF    | 7   | BLUE   | 9
```

Where no number is duplicated except for `FieldA` and `FieldA` will increment depending on the last of `FIELDB`.

Comment: Are you happy using a `CURSOR` in your T-SQL code to achieve this?

Comment: How would I use Cursor to acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a bit silly without some rownumber. I faked a rownumber which I am not showing in my query:

```
;with a as
(
select row_number() over (order by (select 1)) rn, FieldA, FieldB
from 
-- replace next row with your table
(values('ABC', 'GREEN'),('ABC', 'RED'),('ABC', 'Yellow'),('XYZ', 'RED'),('DEF', 'GREEN'),('DEF', 'BLUE')) t(FieldA, FieldB)
), b as
(
select  rn -  dense_rank() over (partition by fieldA order by rn) calc, rn, FieldA, FieldB from a
), c as
(
select FieldA,
calc+ dense_rank() over (order by calc) ID1,
FieldB, 
rn + dense_rank() over (order by calc) ID2 from b
)
select * from c
```

Result:

```
FieldA  ID1 FieldB  ID2
ABC     1   GREEN   2
ABC     1   RED     3
ABC     1   Yellow  4
XYZ     5   RED     6
DEF     7   GREEN   8
DEF     7   BLUE    9
```

Comment: If I want to order the data from my table, how would I order FieldA and FieldB?

Comment: @Tony if you want to order by FieldA and FieldB replace first 'row_number() ...' with 'select row_number() over order by FieldA, FieldB) rn...'

Answer (score 0):

Quite enigmatic for me, where could it be useful. Nevertheless:

```
declare @table table (FieldA varchar(50), FieldB varchar(50))
insert into @table values
    ('ABC','GREEN')
    ,('ABC','RED')
    ,('ABC','Yellow')
    ,('XYZ','RED')
    ,('DEF','GREEN')
    ,('DEF','BLUE')

;with [1](fa) as (select distinct FieldA from @table),
[2](fa, id1) as (select fa, row_number() over (order by fa) from [1]),
[3](fa, fb, id2) as (select FieldA, FieldB, row_number() over (partition by FieldA order by FieldB) from @table),
[4](id1, id2, fa, fb, p) as (
    select NULL, id1, fa, NULL, cast(id1 as binary(4)) from [2]
    union all
    select [2].id1, [3].id2, [2].fa, [3].fb, cast([2].id1 as binary(4)) + cast([3].id2 as binary(4))
    from [2] join [3] on [3].fa = [2].fa),
[5] as (select id1, id2, fa, fb, rn=row_number() over (order by p) from [4])
select t.FieldA, [6].rn as ID1, t.FieldB, [7].rn as ID2
from @table t
    join [5] [6] on [6].fa = t.FieldA and [6].fb is NULL
    join [5] [7] on [7].fa = t.FieldA and [7].fb = t.FieldB
```

Output is (not exactly as you specified, but it can't be exact without some identifier to sort on):

```
FieldA   ID1  FieldB   ID2
-------- ---- -------- -----
ABC      1    GREEN    2
ABC      1    RED      3
ABC      1    Yellow   4
DEF      5    BLUE     6
DEF      5    GREEN    7
XYZ      8    RED      9
```

Comment: This is very useful in adding the increment numbers to the HL segment in x12 837 extract.